# Sending a password securely using gwt and app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I set up session handling on a google app project. This is supposed to allow my users to login and maintain state across pages. I just dumped it into the default greeting service to try it out:

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {
    public void sessionTest(String username) {
        HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
    }
}
```

then attempting to pull it out in my landing project.jsp page:

```
<%
String username = null;
HttpSession mysession = request.getSession(false);
if (mysession.getAttribute("username") != null) {
    username = (String)mysession.getAttribute("username");
}
else {
    username = "(not logged in yet)";
}

<p>You are: 
<%= username %>
</p>
%>
```

It works, but I don't know how to send the data in sessionTest() securely. If I were sending the user's password in there too, it would be in the clear.

This would be ok (I think) if I was using https, but google app engine does not allow you to use https under custom domains (like www.mysite.com), they have to be under the (mysite.appspot.com) domain.

I'm kind of stuck here - how do we send passwords securely? If I was using php, I think I could use digest authentication (I'm not too experienced here) - can we do something like that with gwt + gae?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the existing Users service provided in App Engine? Login is a solved problem, and you definitely won't do it better than Google. Or you could wait for official OAuth support from App Engine, which is on their roadmap: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html

Comment: Hi, yeah the reasoning is that not every one of my users will have a gmail account to sign in with, some users don't want to sign up for a gmail account just to use my app. I know the built-in stuff is good, but it just doesn't work for my users.

Answer (score 0):

Session data is stored on the server, not on the client - only an opaque token is sent to the client, to identify the client's session.

That said, you probably shouldn't store the user's password in the session - why would you want to? - or, indeed, in the clear at all.

Comment: Hi, yes totally agreed, but at some point to 'sign up' or 'login', the users password needs to be sent to the server, at least once. Thereafter the opaque session id can be used instead of sending the password around. It's this one time send I'm wondering about protecting. I see in the roadmap that https for third party sites is on deck, so that should solve this problem.